# msysgit broken from 1.7.11?

Tags: git-svn, msysgit

After updating msysgit to 1.7.11, I get the following error when calling git-svn:

```
$ git svn rebase
Can't locate Git/SVN/Editor.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /lib 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) 
at C:\Program Files\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 81.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Program Files\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 81.
```

Does anyone else experience this problems?

Comment: My TortoiseGit broke when I upgraded to 1.7.11.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**

Seems like this issue is fixed in the meanwhile. Keeping original answer for reference.

---

**Original answer:**

After doing a little research, I found this issue: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/32

Obviously the bug is already known.

Meanwhile, I help myself by manually downloading the missing packages:

```
cd C:/Program\ Files/Git/lib/perl5/site_perl
mkdir -p Git/SVN/Memoize
cd Git/SVN
for i in Editor.pm Fetcher.pm Prompt.pm Ra.pm Memoize/YAML.pm
do
  curl -x $HTTP_PROXY https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/perl/Git/SVN/$i > $i
done
```

Comment: Seems to have fixed this, thanks!  I had to remove `-x $HTTP_PROXY` to get `curl` to work, but otherwise worked great.

Comment: @RandomInsano, the git repo is not dead at all.

Comment: My bad. Seems I didn't mangle the URL properly. Removing my comment.

Comment: Thanks eckes! Note that some users may have to put https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/perl/Git/IndexInfo.pm into C:/"Program Files"/Git/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/IndexInfo.pm as well (I had to).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to browse to the repo but using a slightly different URL:
https://github.com/gitster/git/tree/master/perl/Git/SVN

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already fixed, yust downlad and install Git-1.7.11-preview20120710.exe from here:
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full+installer+official+git