# How to include other folders within the @INC for Perl? (Was: `Can't locate Git.pm in @INC` for svn2git)

Tags: ruby, perl, git, svn, git-svn

I am attempting to import an svn repo into git via `svn2git`.  When I run `svn2git --verbose https://url_to_repo` I end up getting the following output:

```
Running command: git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=trunk --tags=tags --branches=branches https://url_for_repository
Can't locate Git.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /home/cpdirect/perl5/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 80.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 80.
command failed:
2>&1 git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=trunk --tags=tags --branches=branches https://url_for_repository
```

It is obvious that Perl is unable to find the module within the path, however everything I've tried so far on CentOS 5.9 has not yielded results.  For example, the following are installed:

```
git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf
git-svn-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf
cpanel-git-1.7.11.3-1.cp1136
```

Any ideas of how to resolve this issue?

So it turns out that for some reason Perl doesn't know how to look at `/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/`.  If I make links to every module that it needs within `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8` it works seemingly fine and without error.

So the real question here is HOW do you force Perl to look under that `vendor_perl` folder?

Comment: could you upgrade your git installation? There was a bug in 1.7.11 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326301/msysgit-broken-from-1-7-11/11326520#11326520), at least for `msysgit`. Maybe your installation is affected too?

Comment: Blargh. Unfortunately I'm using rpmforge on this CentOS install and I am not seeing an easy path for this upgrade per se.  I'm trying to stick within some of the already set parameters of the admin so that I don't create some problems with Cpanel, etc. so I'm just a little hesitant to do too much with the yum repos.  I am not seeing any indication that the above should be a problem working with 5.9 though, just an oddity in this config perhaps.

Comment: Check this: http://navyblueshellingford.blogspot.de/2009/08/cant-locate-gitpm-in-inc.html

Comment: Well @DanielHilgarth yes, I already saw this earlier prior to posting here actually, however the "answer is [here](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2008/11/msg142075.html)" is not to any meaningful position in the thread where I can ascertain a solution. It simply seems this guy's post is invalid.  Sure seems like it would solve the problem if there were some meat to it.

Comment: @ylluminate: What about this part: "Git.pm comes with git instead of being a part of CPAN. Building a copy of git-core [...] solve it quickly."?

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm not precisely sure of what path to pursue if that is the suggested solution. For example, build git from scratch, looking for some kind of perl libs that it apparently includes, and then moving those over to somewhere in the perl path? If i could find a little more clarity on that part it certainly could help as he's not completely clear, at least to me, of what he's saying there.

Comment: @ylluminate: In that case, I am out of ideas as I am a Windows guy. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've discovered how to add multiple libs and it solves the missing Perl libs:

```
PERL5LIB="/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/:/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi" svn2git -v file:///my/path/to/svn/repo
```